# What is a good way to describe or call something that has been made into something unique and fashionable out of something old and outdated?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, vocabulary

I need a way to describe the process of turning old outdated objects into fashionable new ideas and products.

Comment: Upcycle? Recycle? Refashion?

Comment: What would be an example of, say, a unique and fashionable idea made out of an old, outdated object?

Answer (score 2):

"Upcycled" is a currently popular term for reusing the old, especially in reference to making something worn, faded, or otherwise undesirable valuable (such as taking a ratty leather coat and cutting out the good parts and sewing it into a bunch of iPhone cases.

> to process (used goods or waste material) so as to produce something that is often better than the original: ([Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/upcycle))

Comment: +1. And I've added a definition. Try doing that in your next posts. That's how we roll here.

Comment: W00t. In the future, I shall.

Answer (score 2):

I have heard many people use the word "repurposed" as well. I'm not sure if there needs to be a hyphen after 're'.

Answer (score 0):

> The verb, **[refurbish](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/refurbish?family=refurbished)**.
>
> When you refurbish something, you generally keep the structure the
>   same but improve its looks and possibly its functionality. (as by renovating, re-equipping, or restoring etc.)

- The word refurbish is also often used to describe secondhand technology that has been rebuilt to restore function by replacing a component that has failed.
- make brighter and prettier “refurbished the old castle”

(vocabulary.com/Collins)