# Word for repairing something in a way that changes its function

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means to repair something in such a way that it changes its function.

> Example: The washing machine was broken and I repaired it in such a way that the function of washing machine is no longer washing clothes but, say, now it colours the clothes.

What did I do to the washing machine? Is there any word for that?

I will clarify my question. Actually I'm working on a project in which I made one thing out of another. The washing machine example was "just an example". I can't share what I did but I will give some more examples:

1. I had a bicycle and I changed it to a car.
2. I made a big phone out of my laptop (changed from one thing to another).
3. I had a picture scanner but I changed it to a printer.

Comment: @Jason Bassford. There was a good answer to the near-duplicate, 'word/phrase for changing applicability of something'. 'Repurpose' does not address the repair necessary for _any_ function, and 'upcycle' is not accurate here.

Comment: Having said that, I think this might be a duplicate of [What is a good way to describe or call something that has been made into something unique and fashionable out of something old and outdated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/257236/291924). It seems you want something that's a combination of  **transform** and **jury-rig**, but I see no reason to say that **repurpose** is not already the best overall answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've **adapted** your washing machine.

> **Adapt:** to change, or to change something, to suit different conditions or uses. *[Cambridge English dictionary]*

> **Adapt:** Make (something) suitable for a new use or purpose; modify. *[Oxford Dictionaries]*

Answer (score 26):

That's called *repurposing*.

> **Repurpose (verb):** Adapt for use in a different purpose.
>
> Example: They've taken a product that was originally designed for the CD-ROM and repurposed it for the Microsoft Network. [[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/repurpose)

Example: You repurposed the washing machine for cloth-colourer.

If you fix a broken thing and make something else out of it, I suggest ***[Upcycle](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/upcycle)***.

---

- ***[Transmute](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transmute)*** would also work well. It means *to change something in form, nature, or substance*
- Or use ***[customise](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/customize)*** if you change it according to your needs.
- ***[Revamp](https://www.lexico.com/definition/revamp)***, ***remodel***, ***[transfigure](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transfigure)***
  and [***retool***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retool) could also be used.

> I had a bicycle and I changed it to a car.

For this example, I'd use ***[transmogrify](https://www.lexico.com/definition/transmogrify)***.

Answer (score 6):

How about modify or retrofit? From M-W:

> **[modify](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/modify)**: to make basic or fundamental changes in often to give a new orientation to or to serve a new end

> **[retrofit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrofit)**: to adapt to a new purpose or need

Your example:

> The washing machine was broken and I **modified** it in such a way that the function of washing machine is no longer washing clothes but, say, now it colours the clothes.

> The washing machine was broken and I **retrofitted** it in such a way that the function of washing machine is no longer washing clothes but, say, now it colours the clothes.

Comment: I think these are right but you can modify or retrofit a machine which doesn't need repair (or at least didn't need repair until you started to modify it!). I don't believe that a single word exists to cover both repair and modification, to answer the question completely you would need a phrase such as **repair and modification**, **repair and retrofit** and so on.

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks. I don’t disagree. Your comment also applies to repurpose and the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

The word you are looking for is *hack;* in its original sense, to fix something into something it wasn't before (or more eloquently, *"[An appropriate application of ingenuity](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/H/hack.html)"* )

> I didn't need a raclette grill, so i **hacked** it into a reflow oven.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in the current computer era, you can also use **upgrade** for that purpose. **Upgrading** is the act of replacing a program with a newer version of itself with better performance and new features besides the fixing of whatever errors the previous version had. It has become so common that the use has extended beyond the scope of the software.

Answer (score 1):

To **hack** something.

(usually used in a software/IT context)

Someone hacked the Make program into an init system.